# Run 64bit program from 32bit shell

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I switched from Cygwin to WSL recently and have a problem with Sourcetree and commithooks.

Sourcetree uses it's own version of Cygwin (32 bit) to run git. My development environment runs on WSL (which is 64 bit only).

So what I want to do is call WSL bash from Sourcetrees Cygwin Bash and execute the commithook checks. But this does not work, since Cygwin Bash is a 32bit program and thus cannot execute WSL bash, which is 64bit only. So Cygwin Bash sees the WSL bash as a non-executable file.

Is there a way to break out of the 32bit sandbox on Windows 10 to call a 64bit program?

Comment: *since Cygwin Bash is a 32bit program and thus cannot execute WSL bash, which is 64bit only* -- huh? to the best of my knowledge, there's nothing stopping you form making that call either way, apart from maybe not being able to find the 64-bit executable (cause of WoW filesystem redirection, which only applies to Program Files and System32). If that's your issue, there's ways around it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812882/python-subprocess-call-cannot-find-windows-bash-exe

Comment: @Bob a 32-bit Win32 program can run a 64-bit Windows app without problem. However WSL only supports 64-bit ELF executables and you can't run 32-bit Linux apps

Comment: Your W10 is 32 or 64-bit ?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I took this question as 32-bit *Windows* PE program calling a 64-bit *Windows* PE program (bash.exe, as the invoker for WSL). At no point is a 32-bit ELF involved.

Comment: @Overmind WSL is 64-bit only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've encountered here is [WOW64 filesystem redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx). Because `bash.exe` lives in the *64-bit* `System32` directory, but 32-bit programs see the *32-bit* `SysWOW64` when they ask for `System32`. It's not a matter of being unable to run 64-bit from 32-bit, but rather not being able to *find* the executable you're trying to run in the first place.

You do have a way around it. Quoting from that link:

> 32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32. WOW64 recognizes Sysnative as a special alias used to indicate that the file system should not redirect the access.

So simply call the explicit path via `sysnative`: `%windir%\Sysnative\bash.exe` (or `$WINDIR/Sysnative/bash.exe` within cygwin).

Comment: Thanks, I got confused with SysWOW64 not containing 64-bit executables, but the 32-bit executables.

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly if your OS is 32-bit, but for that you can make a 64-bit VM session if you have a 64-bit processor but have installed a 32-bit host OS.

Comment: Read the question again. OP doesn't have a 32 bit OS.

Comment: It was not specified for the OS.

Comment: "My development environment runs on WSL (which is 64 bit only)."